# Pumping Lemma on CFL Problem

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I have laid out the various cases that would make this not a context free language already and proved all but one for this  set:

\begin{equation} 
A = \{a^f b^g    \mid      f = g^2\}
\end{equation}

I am having trouble trying to explain how if v was a's and x was b's for this problem.  Exactly how would I prove that using this case is it not a context free language.  Steps and explanation would help.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own, we have litte to
work with. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Comment: I also think we have covered this particular question more than once before.